# Gradle stuck at downloading few dependencies (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Gradle stuck at downloading few dependencies
two such dependancies are

```
org.parceler:parceler-api:1.0.4
io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+
```

if i comment them in the gradle file - the build proceeds further
couldn't find the issue, it just shows downloading `parceler-1.0.4.jar` and keeps showing the same message forever unless i manually cancel

**Versions**
Android Studio: 2.0 Beta 5
Gradle: 2.11 (tried with 2.10 also)

Comment: Post your build.gradle file and the error message

Comment: there is no error message, will post the screenshot, gradle file.. (after an hour once i reach home)

Comment: Closing this...
Looks like my wifi is having some issue with SSLlinks (worked on my 4g network)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Have you tried hitting the dependency URL in your browser (or via wget)? Can you download the dependency manually?
2. Try cleaning the gradle cache directory (`%GRADLE_USER_HOME%\caches`)

Comment: 1. Haven't tried in browser, will try and let you know.
2. Tried deleting the .gradle directory, but no change

Comment: Closing this... Looks like my wifi is having some issue with SSL links (worked on my 4g network) –